# Remove extra spaces from data with SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have pipe delimited files and the columns and rows are like

```
Name | City | Address | State |....
```

I want to remove the additional spaces and then load the data. It is very difficult for me to open all the files as it is 1200+ files.

How can i remove extra spaces and load the files?

Comment: derived column using trim()

Comment: Next time please spend some time thinking about the title. "Having issue" is not a good description.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. As an FYI, you should determine which solution you want to pursue; do it; and then let us know what specific problems you are having. We are not here to provide general solutions overall.

It is lamentable the number of questions that are posted here concerning the need for SSIS to perform data sterilization - ideally that is handled before-hand. None the less, one solution is to add a derived column transformation and apply the TRIM() function to each column. If your file has a lot of columns then that may not be much fun and you might want to consider applying a script task or PowerShell script that goes through the entire file and removes the leading and lagging spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this with a csv.

Clean the file first with a script task.

```
string fpath = Dts.Variables["User::fileName"].Value.ToString();
string readContents;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( fpath, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    readContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
    readContents = Regex.Replace(readContents, " | ", "|");   //This code removes the extra space between every column.
    //readContents = Regex.Replace(readContents, " \r\n", "\r\n"); //This removes the extra space at the end of a line
}

File.WriteAllText(fpath, readContents);
```

Add these namespaces:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: You are risking also cleaning pipes inside of strings, but it's their fault for you having to clean their file.

Comment: I added a bonus if there is also an extra space at the end of the line

Comment: He owes you a beer or something for doing his job for him. Just to make sure, the script does not clear out the {CR}{LF}?

Comment: It looks for [space]{CR}{LF} and replaces with {CR}{LF}. it mattered to me because in my case the columns were quote wrapped and could not read "stuff"[space]

Comment: @JWeezy I don't mind helping people as I am really paying it forward from all the knowledge I have already gained from this site.

Comment: Agreed - I have received a lot of help too where answers have even gone above and beyond hopes or expectations. Carry on good sir.

Answer (score 0):

If the spaces are consistent before and after the data in each header and each column, this can be handled in a much simpler way by loading raw data in a staging table and handling all data quality fixes there. Its a good design practice as any addtl issues like this one can be handled there easily. Sql handles such updates much faster than ssis does.